# How do I configure systemd to activate an encrypted swap file?

Tags: linux, encryption, swap, systemd

My [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/how-do-i-set-up-an-encrypted-swap-file-in-linux) produced the commands to add an encrypted swap file:

```
# One-time setup:
fallocate -l 4G /root/swapfile.crypt
chmod 600 /root/swapfile.crypt

# On every boot:
loop=$(losetup -f)
losetup ${loop} /root/swapfile.crypt
cryptsetup open --type plain --key-file /dev/urandom ${loop} swapfile
mkswap /dev/mapper/swapfile
swapon /dev/mapper/swapfile
```

But [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/) uses [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), and I'm having trouble figuring out how to best get systemd to activate my swap file automatically.  [systemd.swap](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.swap.html) suggests that I should have a `dev-mapper-swapfile.swap` unit that looks something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Encrypted Swap File

[Swap]
What=/dev/mapper/swapfile
```

That would execute the `swapon` command.  But I'm not sure how to execute the commands to prepare `/dev/mapper/swapfile`.  I gather that `dev-mapper-swapfile.swap` should declare a dependency on some other unit, but I'm not sure what that unit should look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at:

- crypttab(5)
- systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
- systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8)

Those work for encrypted volumes backed by block devices. They should also work for file backed volumes.

Update:

This does work for me:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-cryptsetup-generator

[Unit]
Description=Cryptography Setup for %I
Documentation=man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8) man:crypttab(5)
SourcePath=/etc/crypttab
Conflicts=umount.target
DefaultDependencies=no
BindsTo=dev-mapper-%i.device
After=systemd-readahead-collect.service systemd-readahead-replay.service
Before=umount.target
Before=cryptsetup.target
After=systemd-random-seed-load.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 'swap2' '/swap.test'     '/dev/urandom' 'swap'
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach 'swap2'
ExecStartPost=/sbin/mkswap '/dev/mapper/swap2'
```

Steps to get this file:

- Create an entry in /etc/crypttab: `swap2 /swap.test /dev/urandom swap`
- Run this command: `/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-cryptsetup-generator`
  This creates unit files in the `/tmp/` directory.
- Search for the generated unit file.
- Open it and *remove* the entry `swap.test.device` from the `After=` and `BindsTo=` directives.
  This is important, as there is by definition no device for the swapfile.
  This prevents the start of the unitfile.
- Copy the unitfile to `/etc/systemd/system/`
- Activate it for your favourite target.

Comment: You may be right, but I don't understand how to apply those to a file backed volume.  In particular, the `/dev/loopN` produced by `losetup -f` is not necessarily consistent between boots.

Comment: cryptsetup itself should allocate the loopback device.
`cryptsetup open /swap.test swap`. I couldn't get it to work when booting (using only /etc/crypttab). A unit which does everything itself with `ExecStart` directives should work.
Maybe this should reported to systemd devs.

Comment: I think the problem might be that it didn't execute `mkswap`.  Because I'm using a random key, the swap file has to be reinitialized each boot.  But I'm not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the end result I came up with based on [t-8ch's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30965/t-8ch) answer.

Put this in `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-cryptsetup@swapfile.service`:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-cryptsetup-generator
# then manually tweaked

[Unit]
Description=Cryptography Setup for %I
Documentation=man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8) man:crypttab(5)
SourcePath=/etc/crypttab
Conflicts=umount.target
DefaultDependencies=no
BindsTo=dev-mapper-%i.device
After=systemd-readahead-collect.service systemd-readahead-replay.service
Before=umount.target
Before=cryptsetup.target
After=systemd-random-seed-load.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 'swapfile' '/root/swapfile.crypt' '/dev/urandom' 'swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256'
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach 'swapfile'
ExecStartPost=/sbin/mkswap '/dev/mapper/swapfile'
```

Put this in `/etc/systemd/system/dev-mapper-swapfile.swap`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Encrypted Swap File
Requires=systemd-cryptsetup@swapfile.service
After=systemd-cryptsetup@swapfile.service
Before=swap.target

[Swap]
What=/dev/mapper/swapfile

[Install]
WantedBy=swap.target
```

One-time setup (as root) to create the swapfile, enable it for future boots, and start using it immediately:

```
fallocate -l 4G /root/swapfile.crypt
chmod 600 /root/swapfile.crypt
systemctl enable dev-mapper-swapfile.swap
systemctl start dev-mapper-swapfile.swap
```

The size in the `fallocate` command determines how big your swapfile will be.

The `/etc/crypttab` entry is not necessary; it's just a way to generate `systemd-cryptsetup@swapfile.service`.  Once that's done, you don't need it anymore.