# Reference encrypted swap partition/device by label/UUID rather than raw device name

Tags: centos, systemd, swap, disk-encryption

**TL;DR**: How can I reference an encrypted swap block device in safe way on CentOS 7?

I'm trying to setup encrypted swap on a CentOS 7.2 VM, which has a swap device presented to it as `/dev/vdb`.  This is essentially how I did it:

```
echo "cryptswap1 /dev/vdb /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256" >> /etc/crypttab
sed -i -e '/\bswap\b/d' /etc/fstab
echo "/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
reboot
```

This works amazingly well: `systemd-cryptsetup-generator` reads the `crypttab` entry and converts it behind the scene without any further tweaks (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64693/how-do-i-configure-systemd-to-activate-an-encrypted-swap-file) for some background; slightly different context).

The concern is the need to refer to the device as `/dev/vdb`.  I have seen block devices move around (this is a VM running on OpenStack) and, should this happen, I understand the content of the block device that's accidentally substituted to `/dev/vdb` would be irrevocably toast!

To refer to the device by label, I've tried following [this excellent Arch article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Swap_encryption#UUID_and_LABEL); unfortunately, this doesn't work because CentOS and/or more recent `crypttab` versions don't seem to support the `--offset` option to preserve the block device attributes.  I have tried to create a dummy `/dev/vdb1` partition, which has not helped.

Many thanks!